# JS getElementsByName with part of id as variable

Tags: javascript

I am using this function to get a total of multiple form fields.

```js
function final_breedte_tot(selectVeld, nr)
{
    var i, totaal = 0;
    var elems = document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[]');
    var l = elems.length;
    for(i=0; i<l; i++)
    {
        totaal += parseFloat(elems[i].value) || 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('final_coil_tot['+nr+']').value = totaal.toFixed(1);
}
```

This function is working correct. Counting all values of `document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[]')`

The content between the brackets of `final_breedte[]` is a 3 or 4 digit number.
The first 2 digits are identical to the variable `nr` in `final_breedte_tot(selectVeld, nr)`

How to get the total of all form fields `final_breedte[]` when the first 2 digits between the brackets are identical as `nr` in `final_breedte_tot(selectVeld, nr)`

Some examples:

```js
final_breedte_tot(selectVeld, 10)
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[101]')
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[102]')
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[103]')
....
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[1010]')
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[1011]')
    
    
final_breedte_tot(selectVeld, 20)
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[201]')
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[202]')
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[203]')
....
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[2010]')
document.getElementsByName('final_breedte[2011]')
```

Comment: In the accepted answer from the dupe replace `id` with `name` and use `nr` to build the partial name

Comment: Thx @Andreas
Once again that someone was able to find an post from 7 years ago!